# Show full SVG with scaling intact

Tags: svg, d3.js, export, png, force-layout

I have a `d3` generated force layout diagram, I need to export it to `png` with the current (user-selected) scaling intact.

By my reasoning this will then grow the `SVG` width and height, so if the `svg` is `1920x1080` and it is 'zoomed' in, the exported `svg` should probably have a much larger width and height to accommodate this.

I have tried everything, and I am missing something, I just can't seem to dynamically calculate the correct values for the output I require.

Here is an **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/aEzQ2/embedded/result/)** of my exported `SVG`, note that there is a lot more information, it is just not visible at that scale.

**EDIT**

Here is my basic exporting code, mostly adapted from highcharts:

```
    serializeSvg: function() {
        /**
         * serialize a xml object to string
         * @param {type} xmlNode the node to use
         * @returns {String|@exp;xmlNode@pro;xml|@exp;window@pro;XMLSerializer@call;@call;serializeToString}
         */
        function serializeXmlNode(xmlNode) {
            if (typeof window.XMLSerializer !== 'undefined') {
                return (new window.XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlNode);
            } else if (typeof xmlNode.xml !== 'undefined') {
                return xmlNode.xml;
            }

            return '';
        }

        var svg = serializeXmlNode(document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0]),
            factor = 2;
        svg = '<svg'
                + ' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"' // xml namespace
                + ' version="1.1"'
                + ' xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"' // for images
                + ' ' + svg.substring(svg.indexOf('<svg ') + 5);

        // highcharts svg sanitizer
        svg = svg.replace(/width="([^"]+)"/, function(m, width) {
                return 'width="' + (width * factor) + '"';
            }).replace(/height="([^"]+)"/, function(m, height) {
                return 'height="' + (height * factor) + '"';
            }).replace(/<rect class="drag"[^<]+<\/rect>/, '')

            // IE specific
            .replace(/<IMG /g, '<image ')
            .replace(/height=([^" ]+)/g, 'height="$1"')
            .replace(/width=([^" ]+)/g, 'width="$1"')
            .replace(/id=([^" >]+)/g, 'id="$1"')
            .replace(/class=([^" ]+)/g, 'class="$1"')
            .replace(/ transform /g, ' ')
            .replace(/:(path|rect)/g, '$1')
            .replace(/style="([^"]+)"/g, function(s) {
                    return s.toLowerCase();
            });

        return svg;
    }
```

and the main zoom/scaling startup for the d3 layout:

```
var layout = d3.layout.force();
var DEFAULT_SIZE = 64;
var GROWTH_SCALE = 1.15;
var SHRINK_SCALE = 1.05;

// creates a new force layout
var force = layout
    .size([w, h])
    .gravity(.06)
    .distance(110)
    //.friction(0.6)
    //.linkStrength(0.4)
    .charge(-((DEFAULT_SIZE * GROWTH_SCALE) * 10))
    .on('tick', tick);

// creates the svg context
var svg = d3.select('.la-container').append('svg:svg')
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)
    .attr('pointer-events', 'all') // set for the pan/zooming
    .append('svg:g') // add a g element for capturing zoom and pan
      .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([0.6, 6.0]).on('zoom', redraw))
    .append('svg:g');

svg.append('svg:rect')
    .attr('class', 'drag')
    .attr('width', w)
    .attr('height', h)
    .attr('fill', 'white');
```

Comment: Are you using the zoom behaviour in d3 to scale your image? You should be able to use zoom.scale() to capture the level of zoom and transform the output SVG appropriately. More information (and javascript code) would be helpful to work out exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes, I am using `d3.behavior.zoom()` and `d3.behavior.drag()`, let's say a user is zoomed in on a graph node containing 500 nodes each 100 pixels apart, he will need to drag to see other nodes, now what I want is that if he clicks export while zoomed in, the complete 500 node graph should be exported in an svg where the whole thing is visible at that zoom level

Comment: Is your problem with capturing the zoom level or with the actual export process? It will be hard to help you without some idea of the javascript you are actually using, and what error messages etc. that your current code is producing.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to keep the zoom level? Unless you're exporting to PNG the resolution really doesn't matter as it's a vector graphic. I would simply reset all the values for zoom and drag on export. The user can zoom and drag the exported SVG/PDF in a viewer of their choice.

Comment: updated question for `png`, thank you for the response, yes, I need to go to png, my users do not have the knowhow to scale it themselves, and if they are zoomed on a certain node (to see picture detail for instance) they will need context to the rest of the graph if it is exported

Comment: For PNG I would do the same (i.e. reset the scale and drag) but multiply the resolution by the old scale factor so that each node looks the same size.

Comment: thank you Lars, I am having a problem doing that, that will answer my question, can you help me achieve that with my input document?

Comment: Well you haven't posted any code, so I can't tell you exactly what's going wrong :) The basic approach though is to first save the zoom value, then set it to 1 and translate to 0,0 and then export multiplying each resolution dimension by the square root of the scale.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, updated with code :)

Comment: Thanks, but that simply exports it as SVG -- how do you generate the PNG?

Comment: just pass the svg straight to the java batik svg transcoder, the png result looks exactly like this: http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/aEzQ2/embedded/result/

Comment: Ah, I see. Well in that case you can simply give the resolution corresponding to the scale to batik, no?

Comment: I have no idea how to do that :(

Answer (score 1):

So, in your d3 startup code, you call `d3.behaviour.zoom.on()` to bind the "redraw" function to the "zoom" action. To get the scale and translation level, you want to capture the `d3.scale`  and `d3.translate` values in this function, something like this (as you haven't posted the code for the redraw function):

```
var scale = 1;
var xtranslate=0;
var ytranslate=0;

var redraw = function(){
    scale= d3.event.scale;
    xtranslate=d3.event.translate[0];
    ytranslate=d3.event.translate[1];

    //your actual code to redraw stufff
}
```

That will get you the scaling and translation values from d3: then you need to apply the appropriate changes to the exported svg: I haven't actually done this, but presumably, you scale the "height" and "width" attributes appropriately (I think this would be just by multiplying the attribute values by the scale value, but I can't be sure).

Answer (score 1):

Apply a view box and multiply it by scale value,

for example 1920x1080, when unzoomed then viewbox=0 0 1920 1080

at scale = 0.5
1920*0.5
1080*0.5
viewbox = 0 0 960 540

Comment: this helped me always constrain the exported image in the export but the size still does not grow with the zoom, and the zoom is now also ignored

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, you might check out some of the options discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/tHRV4uvvHFU/yjIAfdQN8WsJ

D3 should be writing attributes into the DOM, the general expectation is that if you export the SVG as-is, you should get exactly the same view.  It sounds like what you want is a process to render the existing view as png or similar.

Here's an interesting client-side only take http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: thank you, I have been through this. I have no problem rendering the svg, I just need to render it in the correct scale and position, and for that I need to apply the correct transforms and sizes

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this but I think when you export to image you would first need to zoom out back to the starting level. Then serialize the XMLNode. Then increase the size like youre doing now according to the user's scaling level. And then return it.

You should be able to get the user's transformations initially using:

> ## zoom.scale()
>
> If not specified, returns the current zoom scale, which defaults to 1.
>
> ## zoom.translate()
>
> If not specified, returns the current translation vector, which defaults to [0, 0].

Comment: i know all this, but unfortunately it still does not answer my question

Comment: Im sorry I dont think I understand exactly the problem. Is it that the output is scaled to the right size but it is only showing a small portion of the map? Or did I miss something? 
Where are you calling 'serializeSvg()' and what do you do immediately before that?

Comment: your first assumption is correct sir :) serializeSvg comes from a click event

Comment: sorry for the delay but then ok you should zoom back out on click, then call serializeSVG, then zoom back in. or you can look at cloning it on click and doing the above on the cloned element so that the actual element doesnt zoom itself. make sense. hope this isnt too late